# How to identify which combinations of two variables whose outputs are below a certain threshold?

Tags: r, combinations, combn

I have an R coding question which I want to share. Suppose we have the following:

```
z1= c(2, 4, 6, 8)
s1= seq(-13, 14, by = 0.1)
s2= seq(-13, 14, by = 0.1)

Function<-function(s1,s2){
  Y<-matrix(0,nrow=length(s1),ncol=length(z1))
  for (j in 1:length(s1)){
    for (i in 1:length(z1)){
      Y[j,i]<- s1[j]*s2[j] + z1[i]}}
  return(Y)
 }
```

So, s1 and s2 are the inputs, and they can have any values in the interval [-13, 14]. They can have the same value, or different values as well for each time.
Now, I wonder how to identify which combinations of s1 and s2 produce outpots that are (all) less than a certain threshold, say 20. For example, if `s1= 2` and `s2= 4` then we know the function above has four outputs (four because i=1,...,4), which are as follows:

```
Y= 8+ 2 for i=1
Y= 8+ 4 for i=2
Y= 8+ 6 for i=3
Y= 8+ 8 for i=4
```

In this case, all of these outpots are less than 20 so that the combination (2,4) is possible to be chosen. But, how to apply this to the whole range of the possible values of s1 and s2 and then choose only those combinations whose outputs are all less than 20? Any hint is really appriciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With two vectors of different lengths, you can use `expand.grid` + `apply`:

```r
#Create the vectors
s1 = seq(2, 5, by = 1)
s2 = seq(0, 3, by = 1)
z1 = c(2, 4, 6, 8)

#I simplified your function
f <- function(x1, x2) sapply(x1 * x2, `+`, z1) 

gr <- expand.grid(s1, s2)
gr[apply(gr, 1, \(x) all(f(x[1], x[2]) <= 20)), ]
```

Comment: Thanks Mael. But I think the scripts i and j in the function are important. For example, s1*s2+z1 works to multiply each element in s1 with its corresponding element in s2 and then sum it up with the corresponding in z1. This is not what we aim to do. We want to sum up the result of s1*s2 with each element of z1, and if the results (all) below the threshold then it's a good combination of s1 and s2. Also, may I ask why do not we consider the cases when the combination has equal entries so (2,2) for example?

Comment: You could use `sapply` in the function then

Comment: If you have two vector, you can use `expand.grid`

Comment: Check edits in the answer

Comment: I guess OP wants to keep track of all *index* combinations of `s1` and `s2`, thus `expand.grid` might be the thing: *"They can have the same value, or different values as well for each time. "*

Comment: Indeed! I removed the part with `combn`

Comment: Thanks! The last line of the code does not work properly though. I think I should Install some package? It says: 'Error: unexpected input in "gr[apply(gr, 1, \"'

Answer (score 2):

If you care about the ***indices*** of all possible combinations of `s1`, `s2` with a specific filtering condition, you can try `expand.grid` + `subset` like below

```
subset(
    expand.grid(
        j1 = seq_along(s1),
        j2 = seq_along(s2)
    ),
    s1[j1] * s2[j2] < 20 - max(z1)
)
```

Comment: From what I understand of OP's question, they are looking for combinations of `s1` and `s2` only (not with `z1`) too, so an extra step of filter would be needed here, grouping by s1 and s2, and retaining only those groups with the four possible `i` since all outputs should be below 20

Comment: @Maël aha, you are right! Thanks for correcting me. I misread the objective.  I updated my solution.

Comment: @Blue999 maybe replace `max(z1)` by `max(z1+ z2)`